# Having some trouble referencing a Literal in a user control that is included in a Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Having some trouble referencing a Literal in a user control that is included in a Master Page. I'm testing using the following pages (paths probably included unnecessarily...):

```
~/_inc/header.ascx
~/master_pages/partner_header_footer.master
~/credit_check/test_page.aspx
```

**header.ascx** (relevant content)

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="header.ascx.cs" Inherits="_inc_header" %>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/header.css" />
    <div id="header" class="content-header cf">
    <div id="logo"></div><asp:Literal id="contentTitle" runat="server" Text="Customer Service" /> 
</div>
```

**partner_header_footer.master** (relevant content)

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="partner_header_footer.master.cs" Inherits="master_pages_partner" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/_inc/header.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="header" %>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

    <title>Wireless</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <uc1:header runat="server" ID="header" />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Wireless" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
</body></html>
```

**test_page.cs** (relevant content)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         Literal mpLiteral = (Literal)Master.FindControl("contentTitle");
        if (mpLiteral != null)
        {
            mpLiteral.Text = "Customer Service Home";
        }

  }
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, so hopefully someone can point out the error(s) of my ways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Literal is in a UserControl that is inside the Master Page, Master's `FindControl` won't be able to find it.

If you want to make the UC's Literal available to the Master, create a Property in the UC's code-behind:

```
public string MyLiteral { get{ return contentTitle.Text; } set{ contentTitle.Text = value; } }
```

Then, in your Master Page, you can access `header.MyLiteral` to set/get the value.

Now, if you want to make it accessible to Child Pages, you'd then expose it again as a Property, but this time in the Master's code-behind:

```
public string HeaderLiteral { get{ return header.MyLiteral; } set{ header.MyLiteral = value; } }
```

Finally, in the Child Page, you'll need to cast `this.Master` to the type of your Master Page (I think it's `master_pages_partner` based on your MP markup):

```
var castedMaster = (master_pages_partner)this.Master;
if(null != castedMaster)
{
    castedMaster.HeaderLiteral = "Customer Service Home";
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm right out of the box. Thank you, sir! Very much appreciated... ¦-þ

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why the 

    if(null != castedMaster)
    
instead of     

    if(castedMaster!= null)
    
It works like that, but I haven't seen that before...

Comment: It makes no difference, but it's a habit I picked up from my early mentors.  It makes it super clear that you are doing a null-check.  You don't have to scan through the variable name to see what's being checked.  Again, it is a personal preference.