# Access Master Page Object on Child Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, code-behind

I need to access an object created in the codebehind of my master page. I have one master page and a dozen child pages, and the child pages need to access this object. Master page codebehind is as follows:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Manager"] == null) Response.Redirect("/Login");
        Manager Mng = (Manager)Session["Manager"];
    }
```

On my child page I want to be able to do this:

```
int _ID = Mng.ID
```

But "Mng" does not exist in this context. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Have you try to put the code-behind of the masterpage in App_Code directory ?

Comment: Check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723885/having-some-trouble-referencing-a-literal-in-a-user-control-that-is-included-in/18724359#18724359

Comment: He is accessing user controls, not the codebehind...

Comment: The answer adds a property that makes something accessible in the Master Page (doesn't matter if it's code-behind or a control on the page itself) accessible to all child pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to add a public property on the master like:

```
public Manager Mng { get; set; }
```

Set this property with the manager value.  In any page or user control, you can do:

```
((SiteMaster)this.Page.Master).Mng
```

To get the reference.  Note you have to cast the sitemaster, or create an interface like:

```
public interface IMaster
{
   Manager Mng { get; }
}
```

Have your master page implement this interface, and cast the master to type IMaster like:

```
((IMaster)this.Page.Master).Mng
```

Comment: You had me at the first line - Mng wasn't public because it was invalid in that context (because it was within a method). Moving it up solved all my issues! I am able to access it through explicit casting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Zerkey,

> When you use a @MasterType directive, 
>   you can reference  members on the master page as in the following
>   example (VB.Net):
>
> CompanyName.Text = Master.CompanyName
>
> The Master property of the page is already typed to MasterPage_master.

take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h(v=vs.100).aspx
This may help you.